# Wording of the title and heading of flag history page

Tags: bug, status-completed, wording, flag-history

### Situation

The title of a user's flag history page is "Flagged Posts for $(name)", and its h1 heading reads "Flags for $(name)".
[image]
[image]

### Problem with the title

The page lists comment flags too, so the original title "Flagged Posts for $(name)" is technically incorrect. (From @Laurel's comment.)

### Problem with the heading

I think at first sight the heading may be understood by first-time visitors to the page as "Flags *against* $(name)", that is, the list of flags other users raised against the user's questions/answers. When they go through the list, they'll know that's obviously not what the page is for.

### Suggestion

Why not say "Flags by $(name)" as both the title and the h1 heading? It seems a minor problem, but wouldn't it be clearer for users visiting the page for the first time?

Comment: The page also contains comment flags, so "Posts Flagged" is technically incorrect. Either way, "These are the flags that you have raised" makes it clear what follows.

Comment: @Laurel, Good point! I'm adding that to this question. Didn't know that because I never raised a comment flag myself...

Comment: Where does it say 'Flagged posts for"? Your screenshot and the page when I look at it just says "Flags for".

Comment: @Catija, I meant what the <title> tag says. Added another screenshot for that. – Taegyung

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are actually **two** pages that have the header "Flags for $name$" and that actually makes this even more confusing if you're a moderator - because the other page can only be viewed by the moderators on the site.

1. A user's flag history - the flags they have raised and their status. `/users/flag-summary/[userID]`
2. A user's flagged posts - the post flags raised against them and their status. (There's a separate page for comment flags) `/users/flagged-posts/[userID]`

So, you can imagine, this can be quite confusing. It could definitely be made more clear.

I think that for a user's flag history, we could use the headline "Flags raised by $user$" and for the flag history of their posts we could use "Flags raised on posts by $user$".

---

This has been changed (mostly) the way I recommended.

- Flag history page (`/users/flag-summary/[userID]` reads "**Flags raised by $user$**":
  [image: Browser tab that reads "Flags raised by $user$]
- Flagged post page (`/users/flagged-posts/[userID]`) reads "**Flags on posts by $user$**":
  [image: Browser tab that reads "Flags on posts by $user$"]

The former went in as recommended but the latter was shortened slightly. Since the latter page *only* shows flags on posts, we kept that information in the title so that moderators wouldn't be confused about why flagged comments don't appear there.

Comment: "Flags by $username" and "Flags on $username" would be shorter but equally clear.

Comment: Except that's not correct. The page doesn't include all flags, only post flags. :)